# ms windows network activity bytes send and receive in command line

Tags: windows, networking

In windows for example local area Connection Status popup window, there are some activity statistics that show   network activity as bytes send and bytes received. I need to get this numbers periodically in cmd. Is there any way to get that? I tried netstat -e but numbers in both places definitely inrelated. it seems the results in gui is true but not in netstat -e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Powershell:

```
$computer = "LocalHost"
$namespace = "root\CIMV2"
$Tcpip_NI = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface -computername $computer -namespace $namespace
$Tcpip_NI | Select BytesReceivedPersec,BytesSentPersec,BytesTotalPersec
```

In cmd line using just `wmic`:

```
wmic path Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface Get BytesReceivedPersec,BytesSentPersec,BytesTotalPersec
```

Comment: I used wmic and it worked perfect

Answer (score 1):

I need this for zabbix monitoring. I need only one line and this code gives me multiple lines because there are multiple network adaptors on the machine then I changed @TheCleaner's command and made a bat file

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=%1 delims= " %%i  in ('wmic path Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface ^| find "%2"') do     echo %%i
```

then call it from zabbix_agent.conf like this

```
UserParameter=network.Traffic[*],c:\netstatCount.bat $1 $2
```

rest is usual.